# I want to fetch data from DB "start_time" and "end_time", is there any way to display all time per hour in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

I want to fetch data from DB "start_time" and "end_time", is there any way to display all time per hour in Laravel?

For example:
start_time = 8:00
end_time = 11:00

Sample output:

```
8:00 9:00 10:00 11:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to search in database ?

Maybe do this with while in php.

Take the first start_time as 8 (just do like it was not a time)

while 8 < at 11(endtime)
{ update a array to save value : myArray[i]=myHour . ":00"}

Comment: Yes, I needed to. I don't think PHP will work for this because I need to display the time slots.

Comment: I need to know more to help you because it is a little bit confusing for me... And do you already try to do a request ?

Comment: Yes, already did. Thank you for the reply I already found a new way to accomplish it.